# GTM's Noscript tag - is it required?

Tags: google-tag-manager, noscript

In Google Tag Manager, they provide two scripts which must be added to your pages:

```
<!-- place within <head> -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ID');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- place within <body> -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ID"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

I understand that the purpose of the  section is to load when the user does not have javascript enabled.  If I exclude this  tag from my body, what are the repercussions?

Comment: As of privacy concerns, if a user has Javascript disabled you cannot verify/register user consent for privacy purposes (eg: GDPR), so you probably should not use the iframe as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you won't be able to measure pageviews for people who have Javascript disabled (but then you knew that).

The only tags that work in the GTM noscript tag are custom image tags, and if you want to get values from the page they need to appended as key/value pairs (i.e. query string) to the GTM url in the noscript tag.

You have to judge yourself if that's worth the trouble for you.

IIRC you cannot verify a site for Google Search Console via the GTM code if the noscript thing is not implemented, but that is about the worst that can happen.